# Why does the code keep recursing even though a condition for while is set?

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop

The following code is supposed to transform the binary into decimal. However, even though there is a while condition intended to stop it from going forever it still gives me the error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

```
def binary_into_decimal(useful_number, length_of_string):
    working_length = 0
    list_useful_number = list(useful_number)
    power = int(length_of_string - working_length)
    will_be_summed = []
    current_number = int(list_useful_number[working_length])
    calculation = current_number * (2 ** power)
    while working_length < (length_of_string + 1):
        will_be_summed.append(calculation)
        working_length += 1
        binary_into_decimal(useful_number, length_of_string)
        print("hey")
```

Comment: Remember that `working_length` starts at 0 on every call, and you are not changing `useful_number` or `length_of_string`, so you are doing the same processing over and over and over.

Comment: Because `working_length` is effectively always zero when the while condition is evaluated.

Comment: You call the function recursivley without modifying the arguments at any point.

Comment: @TimRoberts oh, I see, thank you, how do I make it so I can add to working length during each loop?

Comment: I don't know what `working_length` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

It is an infinite loop because you are re-initializing the value of **working_length** back to **0** every time you call `binary_into_decimal(useful_number, length_of_string)` in while loop. So it actually never overcome the condition of the while loop.

In while loop every time you execute `binary_into_decimal(useful_number, length_of_string)` . First line of your function **(working_length = 0)** *gets executed*.

Answer (score 0):

Although recursion is a dumb way to do this, here's how you can change a binary string to decimal recursively:

```
def binary_into_decimal( bits, sofar = 0 ):
    if not bits:
        return sofar
    sofar *= 2
    if bits[0] == '1':
        sofar += 1
    return binary_into_decimal( bits[1:], sofar )

print( binary_into_decimal( '1100' ) )
print( binary_into_decimal( '10101' ) )
```

Here's a different way that doesn't carry the accumulator as a parameter:

```
def binary_into_decimal( bits ):
    if not bits:
        return 0
    return int(bits[-1]) + 2 * binary_into_decimal( bits[:-1] )

print( binary_into_decimal( '1100' ) )
print( binary_into_decimal( '10101' ) )
```